# Blog only showing code

Tags: php, code, apache

I would like to have some help.
I host a wordpress blog in my raspberry pi running apache2, but when I browse the blog it only shows the code as you can see here http://lifeonpi.sytes.net/raspgrammer/

what can i do? 
what is the problem with it? 
any help?

Comment: Did you make any code changes lately?

Comment: just installed the blog

Comment: Please elaborate on what is your web server stack currently.

Comment: server apache2 with php5 lamp mysql

Comment: don't know if this helps but http://lifeonpi.sytes.net/phpinformation.php/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to install PHP along side apache2 : http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n1vS2_-Xz9o

Comment: so i need to install lamp?

Comment: don't know if this helps but http://lifeonpi.sytes.net/phpinformation.php/

Comment: Yes, now you have PHP installed and the code runs, now you need to setup the code correct. But that is a different questing, I'm happy to help but accept the answer and start a new one.